# Cakephp3 Auth - allow some controllers to work without authoriziation

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Today i wanted to use Cakephp3 auth component.

I have studies cakephp3 blog tutorial and auth documentation.

I have followed Blog tutorial, and for now everything works fine, like login,logout etc...

I wanted to have UsersController to be protected and used only when i will logged in.

And this is ok, but now i saw that i need to login to other controllers actions, for example i have PagesController, which should be public.

I found this in docs:

```
// Allow only the view and index actions.
$this->Auth->allow(['view', 'index']);
```

But i have a lot of actions, and listing actions in this function may be problematic.

My question is: How can i globally set all actions of UsersController to be protected, and all the rest of controllers to be public ?

Thank You.

Comment: First of all you should make sure that you are using the correct terms. Authorization seems different from "_protected and used only when i will logged in_", which sounds more like Authentication.

Answer (score 7):

For UsersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        // allow only login, forgotpassword
         $this->Auth->allow(['login', 'forgotpassword']);
    }
}
```

For Other controller. (Example: PagesController)

```
class PagesController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
       // allow all action
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is damn right. I was trying it as $this->Auth->allow(' * ') and was wondering why it was not working. Just removed ' * ' and it worked! Thank you! (ignore the space on both sides of * here)

Answer (score 2):

In your appsController, you can add below code. You must add all the view names in `$this->Auth->allow('ViewName')`.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    // You should not add the "login" action to allow list. Doing so would
    // cause problems with normal functioning of AuthComponent.
    $this->Auth->allow(['Index', 'View', 'Edit', 'CustomViewName']); // NOTE: DO NOT ADD VIEWS THAT ARE USED BY YOUR USERSCONTROLLER.
}
```

And from UsersController, you can remove `$this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout']);`. This is how I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use ControllerAuthorize.It will allows you to handle authorization checks in a controller callback.Add this setting in your app component.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => 'Controller',
]);
```

Then  you can prevent or allow access by `isAuthorized()`

example :

```
 public function isAuthorized($user) {
        if ( isset($user['role']) == 'yourRole' ) {
                return TRUE;
        }

        else {
            header("location: Router::url('/', true)");
            exit();
       }
 }
```

For details 
[cake doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize)

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`$this->Auth->deny(['controllers name that you want to authorize']);`